# Fixed header with in a scrollable div

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I have a bootstrap table with in a scrollable div. Wrapping table with in div help me fix my th and td alignment issues but with this my table headers also scroll and I want them to be fixed.

```
  <div class="table-wrapper">
                            <table class="table" id="tblfiles">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th data-field="Date" class="col-md-2" style="width:100vw;">Alert Date</th>
                                        <th data-field="Files" class="col-md-2" style="width:100vw;">Files</th>
                                        <th data-field="fileName" class="col-md-2" style="width:100vw;">Received Time</th>
                                        <th data-field="ReceivedTime" class="col-md-2" style="width:100vw;">Received Time</th>
                                        <th data-field="Delete" class="col-md-1" style="width:100vw;"></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="tblBodyFiles">
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            </div>
```

CSS

```
.table-wrapper {
max-height: 200px;
overflow: auto; 
display: inline-block;
```

}

All I want to do now is make th fixed, Thanks a lot. Help is much appreciated

Comment: You are more likely to get good help if you provide a complete example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . As is, your table fits in table-wrapper so there's no scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolute position the thead row and give the table some padding so the first row doesn't move under it. This way the header row stays fixed to the top of the table.

```
table {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

thead {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding Steven. But this does not work. It messes up alignment and also header is still not fixed :(

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:sticky` to each `th` element. You have to do it to the `th` elements, not the `thead` or `tr` elements. This should get you started:

```css
.table-wrapper {
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @dgrogan, I did this `<th data-field="Date" class="col-md-2" style="width:100vw; position:sticky !important;">Alert Date</th>` and looks like it is not being picked up. th 's are still scrollable and When I check in developers tool by clicking F12 I see  position:sticky is not recognised.